# De-convolving Instrument Response from Signal (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, phase, ifft

So I am trying to remove instrument response (phase lag) from some magnetics data. The code I am trying to use is below. I can't figure how to reconstruct the file together properly. The approach I am trying now is to subtract the phase lag and reconstruct the signal. I realize that there is maybe another function I could use her.  I've had phase rotation suggested, but my phase lag is frequency dependent, so I really need to be able to convolve the vectors somehow... Thank you for your help!

```
load('coil') % Load coil response data
time = 1/40:1/40:288000/40; %Create time vector for later plotting
%Removing Coil Response
T2=load(mag); %Load data
y=abs(real(T2.y.data));
t = angle(T2.y.data); %Create a phase vector for the original data
Fs = 40; %Sampling frequency
NFFT = size(y);
NFFT=NFFT(1);
j = [y,t]; %Create a matrix of amplitude and phase
Y = fft2(j); %2D transform
F = ((0:1./NFFT:1-1./NFFT)*Fs);


F1=coil(:,1); %Load coil phase delay
P=coil(:,3);

Pnew=interp1(F1,P,F); %Create the phase delay vector of the same length
Pnew(1) = Pnew(2);
Pnew=Pnew';

t_fin = t-Pnew %Subtract the pahse delay from the original phase vector

%Mag_Final = ifft(abs(Y));
%Phase_Final = ifft(phaseF);

j_fin = [y,t_fin]; %Create matrix of amplitude versus correct phase

Final = ifft(j_fin); %Invert the transform

y = struct('data',Final);
save('y')
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're having with the current code?

Comment: Current code returns a 288000x2 matrix (the files are 288000x1).  I understand this is because I'm using a fft2 function, but I couldnt figure out any other way to isolate the phase vector to manipulate it.  I'm thinking that I need a different approach to subtracting the phase or a way or "rewrapping" the phase into the function so to speak, but I'm not sure about how to go about it.

Comment: Just to get things straight: as I understand it, y and t are the magnitude and phase of time domain data, whereas coil is the frequency spectrum of the coil response. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly correct.  y and t are the original data in the time domain and coil(:,1). coil(:,3) uploads are frequency and phase respectively.  So the phase lag I'm working with is frequency dependent.